# Check if variable is float('inf') with Jinja

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I need to check on flask template if a variable is float('inf'), I found in another thread this: `{% if data.variable|int == 0 %}` and it work when variable is a string but it didn't worked with float('inf'). The possible values of the variable are int or float('inf').

It occurred to me that I could pass `data.inf = float('inf')` and compare it to the variable but I'd rather do it directly than pass yet another variable to the template.

Comment: What do you mean "it didn't work"?  Do you mean that `float('inf')` did not compare equal to zero?  Why would you expect those to be equal?

Comment: Could you do the check in python itself before passing it to the template?

Comment: Add your own `isinf` filter - that would probably be the most readable format. Since you've tagged this with `flask`, I'm guessing you can decorate a function with `@app.template_filter('isinf')`, and use the built-in `math.isinf`: `import math @app.template_filter('isinf'), def is_inf(v): return math.isinf(v)`, and then use `data.variable | isinf` in your template. See https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.1.x/templating/#registering-filters

Comment: @JohnGordon If you compare `'some string'|int == 0` it returns True, I supposed that would be the same in this case but no.
@NicholasHansen-Feruch No, I can't do it before.
@MatsLindh Great, I've never create a filter so it didn't comes to my head... That's a great idea. Thanks!